# How to get all child views to overlap and fill their parent w/ React Native Flexbox

Tags: react-native, react-native-flexbox

I want to have all children filling the available space, and overlapping one another, so only the last child is visible.

```
<View style={???}>
  <View style={???} /> // Not visible (if bg color set on next child)
  <View style={???} />
</View>
```

I've tried various combinations of `flex`, `position`, `alignSelf: stretch`, etc., and can't find a winning combo.

Comment: Position absolute and z index to stack views on top of each other

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of what you are trying, and another for what you are expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

**component/index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    View,
} from 'react-native';

import style from './style';

export default class Component extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={style.root}>
                <View style={style.childOne} />

                <View style={style.childTwo} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**component/style.js:**

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default StyleSheet.create({
    root: {
        flex: 1,
        position: 'relative',
    },
    child1: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    },
    child2: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    },
});
```

So, `View` with `root` style will fill all space of its parent since it has `flex: 1`. And it has `position: relative`, so the children with absolute positioning will act accordingly.

`View`s with `child1` and `child2` both have absolute positioning (`StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject` is a shortcut for `{position: 'absolute', top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0}` [docs here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html)). `child1` and `child2` will overlap and `child2` will be on top of `child1` since it is rendered later.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and explanation, this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: How can we get the parent view root in child component ?